# Fastest way to clear every kth bit in boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, bitset

What is the fastest way to clear every `kth` bit in a `boost::dynamic_bitset`, optionally from offset `j`?

Currently I'm doing this which is pretty darn slow (pseudocode):

```
for (i = j; i < bitset.size(); i += k) {
    bitset[i] = 0;
}
```

Millions of bit-clears have to be done, so that's why I'm looking for a fast way to do it.

Comment: Could you fix your pseudocode to more accurately describe your current solution? That code clears the `ith` bit many times. Also, why are you incrementing by `2*k` instead of `k`?

Comment: @Rob Adams: Woops! Fixed :) That 2*k and those errors got in because I copy/pasted from a file and then quickly changed some letters for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For very large bitsets, compute a mask n bits long (where n is your native size, e.g. 64 for x86_64) as Nim suggested, apply it.
If your native length is not a multiple of k, shift it accordingly.
So if you have a native length of 10 and want to set only every 3rd bit of a 30 bit-long bitset, you'd need 3 passes like this:
First  10 bits: 0010010010
Second 10 bits: 0100100100
Last   10 bits: 1001001001
So, after applying each mask you'd need to shift it (n%k) bits to the left.

Repeat until you're done.

Comment: `If your native length is not a multiple of k, shift it accordingly.` I didn't understand this part.

Comment: Let's assume your processor's native length is 10 bits and you want to reset every 3rd bit. Your mask is 0010010010. For the next 10 bits, your mask has to be 0100100100, your next mask is 1001001001 etc. In the end, you have one big mask (0010010010|0100100100|100...) you split at your processors native length

Answer (score 1):

okay, not sure if this is faster, but I think you can test:

The key operation is the construction of the mask bit sets, you should have a table of pre-constructed masks (which will allow you to reset every `k`th bit up to every 32nd bit [on my platform `unsigned long` is 32-bits]). Then the expensive operation is constructing a full mask of the same size as the input - if it's always the same size, and memory is not a constraint, you can simply construct a lookup table for this as well, and then it's simply `&`ing the two bit sets.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> orig(64);
  for (int i = 0; i < orig.size(); ++i) {
    orig[i] = rand() % 2;
  }

  std::cout << orig << std::endl;

  unsigned long mask = 0x88888888; // reset every 4th bit
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> mbits(numeric_limits<unsigned long>::digits, mask);

  while(mbits.size() < orig.size())
    mbits.append(mask);
  mbits.resize(orig.size()); // incase not aligned
  mbits <<= 5; // arbitary starting point (i.e. j)
  std::cout << mbits << std::endl;

  mbits.flip();

  std::cout << mbits << std::endl;

  orig &= mbits;

  std::cout << orig << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: Okay, just tested it very roughly, and you can see the result here: http://www.ideone.com/ez3Oc, with a pre-constructed mask, it can be almost +40% quicker...

Comment: The problem is, I won't be just using `1 <= k <= 32`, `k` can be much larger.

Comment: in that case, I think what you have is the most optimal, if you need to dynamically generate a mask for every `k`th bit, you may as well immediately set the bit at that index to 0. The above is good if your `k` is in that range.